# What's the good way to set redux state from URL? (I care abt one way only - for sharing links)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux

I am creating a single page calculator with React-Redux. Think simplified tax calc or mortgage calc, maybe a dozen of params for user to control and zero routing (not right now at least). I want user to be able to Share his calculations with the others, so e.g. if he clicks Share button and posts to facebook similar to http://www.magiccalc.com?taxYear=2016&plannedIncome=60000&etc=etc anybody who clicks that link arrives to the page initialized with the given parameters, maybe with a bit of initialization animation even.

What would be a good way of doing it?

I am in the research phase for now, so ready for compromises. Url params can be state values or params for some SET_VALUES action, they can go after hashsign, or with the full router, they can be base64 or elsehow coded as well.

Best regards,
Artem.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has one and only one page, I'd just use normal javascript to parse the url to get the params' values and set them in the state in "componentWillMount" method.

If your app has multiple pages (i.e. routes). It depends on how you are handling route in your application. For me I use [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux), which provides a nice way to access the router's props from the 2nd argument of mapStateToProps. For example, say your url is "http://myapp/?someParam=someValue", you can grab the value of "someParam" as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = ( state, ownProps ) => {
    return {
        someParamValue: ownProps.location.query.someParam,
    }
}
```

Then you can set this "someParamValue" into your app state. Again I'd do this in "componentWillMount" method.

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.urlParamActions.setParamValue(this.props.someParamValue);
}
```

If you use react-router, you can do [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/latest/docs/Introduction.md#getting-url-parameters)